# SYMFONY - Correctly setup PDO-MYSQL on os x 10.5

Tags: php, mysql, macos, pdo, symfony-1.4

I'm having an issue with symfony and mysql setup on mac os x 10.5.8

When trying to access a newly created module, i get:

```
500 | Internal Server Error | Doctrine_Connection_Exception

Couldn't locate driver named mysql.
```

I had the same error message when trying to execute doctrine:insert-sql to create my database tables. I fixed this by downloading PDO_MYSQL and installing as per these instructions:

```
cd ~/Downloads/PDO_MYSQL-1.0.2/PDO_MYSQL-1.0.2

phpize

./configure '--with-pdo-mysql=shared,/usr/local/mysql'

make

sudo make install
```

I also added

```
extension_dir = "/usr/lib/php/extensions/no-debug-non-zts-20060613"
extension=pdo_mysql.so
```

to my php.ini file.

When i do a php -m I do have pdo_mysql and PDO installed. However when I check out a phpinfo(); file with my browser, under PDO drivers, I only have sqlite and sqlite2 enabled, not mysql.

I must be missing something here! Any help with this would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Did you restart httpd after updating the php.ini file?

Comment: At this point, I'd recommend going with a nice, easy PHP installation like [Zend Server CE](http://www.zend.com/en/products/server-ce/downloads)

Comment: @Phil: Something seems to be up, manually compiling PDO is unusual.

Comment: Yup everything has been restarted :-( still no joy. As I mentioned, installing PDO_MYSQL overcame my previous 'Couldn't locate driver named mysql' error when executing 'doctrine:insert-sql', however I am still greeted by this error message when trying to access a newly created module with my browser

Comment: @MikePurcell apparently the distribution of PHP that comes with OS X doesn’t have the pdo_mysql.so library loaded.

Comment: Sorry, I know it's the software equiv of "did you plug your computer in", but did you clear symfony cache?

Comment: I have now (I can't say I had thought of that), but still now joy

Comment: Do a search and make sure there aren't multiple copies of php.ini laying around.

Comment: Nope. I can only find one unfortunately...

Answer (score 0):

Solved my problem by upgrading my PHP version to entropy.ch version.

Didnt work straight out of the box though, I had to manually swap my php modules over as per instructions here: https://discussions.apple.com/thread/1201106?start=0&tstart=0

Fixed in the end. Onwards and Upwards.